# Highslide - close expanded image when different thumbnail is clicked

Tags: highslide

I would like to create an event on thumbnails that would close an open expander before opening the new expander without using dimming. Thinking the expanded images require the same id that each thumbnail would check to see if that id was open before opening a new one, closing the image before opening the new one.

http://www.rpk4.com/product/2013-2014-bogner-karea-d-jacket-womens-blue.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No need for any fancy scripting. That functionality is already built into Highslide JS. Just use:

```
hs.allowMultipleInstances = false;
```

You can add it to your highslide.config.js file.

See: http://highslide.com/ref/hs.allowMultipleInstances

Comment: Awesome, thank you. My problem now (and I should have mentioned it earlier) is that I want to be able to have 2 different expanders open at the same time. To explain: thumbnails for a top image and thumbnails for a bottom image. top and bottom to be shown at the same time, but when a new top image is selected i would like the opened top image expander to close and have the new one replace it, same with the bottom image.

Comment: That can be accomplished by having two different slideshow groups on the page. This barebones example shows you how to do it: http://highslide.com/examples/mini-galleries.html